# Convert from unrecognised character to normal form

Tags: java, utf-8, character

I have a error with my file. That is, all the characters are like `"GiÃ¡Â»âºi tÃÂ­nh".` I want to use Java to write a program that convert those characters to normal ones. I have tried to convert them to bytes and then convert again to String but it remained the same.

Comment: Your file doesn't contain characters, but **bytes**. If you are seeing the characters you mention, you have already assumed a specific **encoding** for those bytes. You didn't share any details on that count with us, though.

Comment: What do you see if you use a hex editor or dump? e.g. Unix `hexdump -C filename` or Windows `debug`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the encoding of the file in order to do this. Java internally represents all Strings as UTF-16; in order to fix the issue, you need to know the encoding of the file, and use that encoding when reading the file: http://goo.gl/PoBgo (Java API Docs)